# Перемещение div'а с помощью CSS

Tags: javascript, css

Нужно сместить элемент на 50 пикселей, написал такой скрипт - не смещается.

```
document.getElementById("holter").style.left += 50 + 'px';
```

Если просто написать

```
document.getElementById("holter").style.left = 200 + 'px';
```

тогда работает, но мне нужно именно прибавлять + 50 пикселей.

Comment: += к чему прибавляет? Как JS должен интерпретировать, если там "100px"? попробуйте просто в консоли набрать document.getElementById("holter").style.left, что там будет? А если прибавить "100px"+50+"px" что получится? Поэтому надо отказаться от такой записи и предварительно преобразовать текущее значение через parseInt()

Comment: Я как бы делал уже то, о чем говорю, но старый код потерял.

Comment: При чём тут "делал"? Надо конкретно ответ, без желания подумать головой даже при конкретном ответе? document.getElementById("holter").style.left = parseInt( document.getElementById("holter").style.left ) + 50 + 'px';

Comment: Делал я без parseInt, поэтому и задаю вопрос здесь, потому что забыл как.

Comment: @BaNru прикольно... немного потестил, ваш вариант работает только в случае, если стиль задан именно в HTML-элементе, `style="left: 50px"`... а если задается через CSS - не сработает)

Comment: holter.style.transform = "translateX(50px)"

Answer (score 1):

Метод `getBoundingClientRect()` возвращает объект, содержащий нужную вам информацию. Оттуда можно достать и `left`, чтобы к нему суммировать 50:

```js
let holter = document.getElementById("holter");
holter.style.left = holter.getBoundingClientRect().left + 50 + 'px';
```

```css
#holter, #test {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center; font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div id="holter">+50</div>

<br><br><br><br>

<div id="test"></div>
```

Еще демо:

```js
let bubu = document.getElementById('bubu');

console.log( bubu.getBoundingClientRect() );
```

```css
#bubu {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="bubu"></div>
```

А если нужен вообще какой угодно стиль, его можно достать так:

```js
let bubu = document.getElementById('bubu');

console.log( 'font-size: ' + window.getComputedStyle(bubu).fontSize );
console.log( window.getComputedStyle(bubu) );
```

```html
<div id="bubu">bubu</div>
```

Comment: а если нужно изменить не позиционирование, а например к размеру текста добавить +3 пикселя?

Comment: Добавил в конце ответа*